# Windows key on a deleted SSD

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, product-key

I want to install Windows 10 on a OEM PC (no key is needed) on a SSD from my other laptop, where previously also Windows 10 was installed (not OEM but bought key).
I have formatted the SSD (no secure erase was performed).

Once I have put this SSD in the OEM PC and install the Windows 10 will it be possible to recover the bought Windows 10 key from the previous Windows installation?

Comment: Sure; It’s a simple command to change the key;  What does your research show?

Comment: My issue is that I want to sell the OEM Notebook. Thus I want to replace its original HDD. I want to put my old SSD in this laptop. But on this old SSD Windows 10 is installed using installation key I bought from “offline” store.
I have formatted this SSD. I fully understand that when I put this SSD into the laptop and make a fresh Windows 10 install the previous data will not be fully erased. Would it be possible to recover the bought Windows key (which I slit wanna use for my purpose).

Comment: What?  You can’t transfer OEM licenses;  Your retail license would only be used if you specifically used it;  If you are selling the laptop, and it’s using its original key, only somebody with knowledge of your key could use it;

Comment: Somehow we talk of different things I think. I put it like this: if I have an SSD with Windows 10 ( activated with retail Key). Than format this drive and give it to someone. Can this person recover the key?

Comment: No; They cannot;

Answer (score 0):

If you bought a key from Microsoft or a licensed vendor, this is called a "retail" key.
That key can be moved to another computer, although there are usually some limitations
on the number of times that this can be done in given number of months.

On the other hand, if you bought a cheap serial on the internet, there is a good
chance that it is an OEM serial that is being sold in a manner that is inconsistent
with its licensing contract (but usually works even so).

You should ensure that you posses the serial itself, then enter it when Windows
demands it for activation. However, recovering the key from a formatted
disk will not be easy.